# Custom domain does not work for homestead

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I'm brand new to using homestead for developing laravel sites locally. I followed two different tutorials for setup and have reinstalled about 5 times, but the custom domain name does not work for me. I'm working on a windows 10 machine and am using Virtualbox. I'm able to see the test site when I browse to 192.168.10.10 in my browser. I can ping 192.168.10.10 and get all of the packets send and receive fine. I can also ping obsessories.dev it sends and receives all of the packets successfully. I also tried changing my hosts file to use 127.0.0.1 based on another answer I saw on SO, but that didn't work for me. I use the command

> vagrant reload --provision

each time I make any change to Homestead.yaml and my hosts file. I have noticed that firefox and chrome both redirect to https://obsessories.dev, but I'm not sure if that's a problem or not. I appreciate any help or insight on this in advance!

Here is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\******\Projects\web\ssh\publickey.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\******\Projects\web\ssh\privatekey.ppk

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\******\Projects\web\sites
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: obsessories.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/code/obsessories/public

databases:
    - homestead

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# zray:
#  If you've already freely registered Z-Ray, you can place the token here.
#     - email: foo@bar.com
#       token: foo
#  Don't forget to ensure that you have 'zray: "true"' for your site.
```

output for pinging 192.168.10.10

> ping 192.168.10.10
>
> Pinging 192.168.10.10 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 192.168.10.10:
>   bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms
>   TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64 Reply from
>   192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.10.10:
>       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

output for pinging obsessories.dev

ping obsessories.dev

> Pinging obsessories.dev [192.168.10.10] with 32 bytes of data: Reply
>   from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.10.10:
>   bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms
>   TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.10.10:
>       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: Try it with a different TLD Chrome enforces a requirement for ssl on .dev domains, I run mine on .local or .test

Comment: Oh no kidding, I didn't realize that. I'll try that when I get home, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe's suggestion worked for me. I changed the domain to .local instead and reloaded vagrant and works just fine now.